# touchpad acting erratic in 12.10

Tags: mouse, touchpad

I have a fresh-ish install of 12.10 and the touchpad has been acting strangely. First it's ignoring some of my settings, for example, I usually turn off the "Enable mouse clicks with touchpad" setting because I accidentally "click" when I don't want to. Second, the touchpad will occasionally go into a state where it jumps all over the screen and is completely unusable. When it's in this state I have to rmmod and reload the psmouse driver, I've done this a lot. Looking back at my shell command history I see it done ten times in the past day or so. It seems that this happens most often when I have a my thumb on the touchpad and I click the mouse button.

So I'm wondering how can I first of all disable the mouse clicks feature and second, any ideas why it's going into this jumpy state?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/1041063).Well it has been solved.

Install the bug fix:

> sudo apt-add-repository ppa:a7x/bug1041063
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get upgrade

Comment: You sure that's right? I don't see that PPA on your LP page and I get a 404 when I tried it.

Comment: The page opens without any problem for me. Try searching for Bug #1041063 in Google in case you still get a 404 error.

Comment: Not the bug, it's your PPA that's broken: Not allowed here
Sorry, you don't have permission to access this page or the information in this page is not shared with you.

You are logged in as Matt Fischer.